# _.findWhere() is not giving result for property value undefined

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I have a requirement to add new objects to an existing array of objects where duplicates are not allowed and the uniqueness of the objects is based on all the properties of the object. The object contains properties:
1. departmentId
2. equipmentId
3. sectionId
4. serviceId

According to my requirements, equipmentId is an optional field i.e. it may be undefined when there is no value for it. I wrote below for it:

```
$scope.isDuplicateRecord = function(){
    var dupCheck =  _.findWhere($scope.equipmentServiceMaps,{departmentId:$scope.equipmentServiceMap.department.departmentId,
                                            equipmentId:$scope.equipmentServiceMap.equipment.equipmentId,
                                            sectionId:$scope.equipmentServiceMap.section.sectionId,
                                            serviceId:$scope.equipmentServiceMap.service.serviceId})

    if(dupCheck== undefined){
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
```

This code is working fine with all values of quipmentId except undefined, i.e. if there is an existing object with the same departmentId, sectionId, serviceId and equipmentId as undefined. It's not finding that object and returning undefined hence My check is failing.

When I change to code to the basic for loop it worked, but I want to go ahead with the underscore. Below is my workaround code with for loop,

```
var dupCheck = undefined;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.equipmentServiceMaps.length; i++){
        if($scope.equipmentServiceMaps[i].departmentId == $scope.equipmentServiceMap.department.departmentId 
        && $scope.equipmentServiceMaps[i].sectionId == $scope.equipmentServiceMap.section.sectionId
        && $scope.equipmentServiceMaps[i].serviceId == $scope.equipmentServiceMap.service.serviceId
        && $scope.equipmentServiceMaps[i].equipmentId == ($scope.equipmentServiceMap.equipment? $scope.equipmentServiceMap.equipment.equipmentId : undefined)){
            dupCheck = $scope.equipmentServiceMaps[i];
            console.log(dupCheck);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(dupCheck == undefined){
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
```

Please suggest how can I go ahead with the underscore.js

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for some syntactic sugar, this may help:

```
var search = {
    departmentId:$scope.equipmentServiceMap.department.departmentId, 
    equipmentId:$scope.equipmentServiceMap.equipment.equipmentId, 
    sectionId:$scope.equipmentServiceMap.section.sectionId, 
    serviceId:$scope.equipmentServiceMap.service.serviceId
}

_.find($scope.equipmentServiceMaps, function(obj) {
    return _.isMatch(_.defaults({}, obj, attrs), attrs);
})
```

The normal `_.findWhere` function works more or less like this:

```
_.find($scope.equipmentServiceMaps, function(obj) {
    return _.isMatch(obj, attrs);
})
```

In my version, any undefined values in the object will be substituted by values from the search attrs. The original object is unmodified.